# IE10 - Inserting new line in <textarea> on keydown with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, newline, internet-explorer-10

I have a textbox where you type in your messages. Everytime the user presses `ctrl` + `enter`, a new line is created and the cursor should go to the next line. My code works on FF and Chrome. But in IE10, it behaves differently.

FF and Chrome behavior: When pressing `ctrl` + `enter`, the `<textarea>`'s value is stored inside a variable and then the `<textarea>` is applied with `.focus().val('').val(prevMsgVal += "\r\n")` which focuses on the `<textarea>` then clears its value and then placing a new value taken from the `prevMsgVal` variable (where the message before `ctrl` + `enter` was pressed is stored) is  appended with "\r\n". - This works like the FB chat.

But in IE10, when you press `ctrl` + `enter`, it places a `space` or `whitespace` or something. And when you type in something, it goes to the new line!

Here's my current code:

```
if (evtobj.keyCode == 13 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
    $('#msgArea').focus().val('').val(prevMsgVal += "\r\n")
    $('#msgArea').scrollTop = $('#msgArea').scrollHeight - $('#msgArea').clientHeight;
}
```

This only happens in IE10 but not in FF and Chrome. Did I append the new line the wrong way? Is there any other way to do this newline thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution to IE10's behavior, but I found a nifty fix to this problem here: [David Walsh's Move Caret to end of TextArea](http://davidwalsh.name/caret-end)

```
if (evtobj.keyCode == 13 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
            evtobj.preventDefault()
            var tArea = document.getElementById("msgArea");

            $('#msgArea').focus().val('').val(msgBoxVal += "\r\n")
            moveCursorToEnd(tArea)
            $('#msgArea').scrollTop = $('#msgArea').scrollHeight - $('#msgArea').clientHeight;
}
```

D. Walsh's function:

```
function moveCursorToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

It now moves the cursor/caret to the newline (which is the end of the textarea since I inserted it in `val(msgBoxVal += "\r\n")`)